# Integral involving Bessel function, Struve Function and Exponential Function.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, matlab, bessel-functions

I am trying to solve solve an integral of the form:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-2x/a}[H_0(x/b)-Y_0(x/b)]dx$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-2x/a}H_o(x/b)dx-\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-2x/a}Y_o(x/b)dx$$
$Y_n$ is Bessel function with $n=0$ and $H_n$ is Struve function with $n=0$ How can I solve these integral? Any hints please.

Can these be solved using MATLAB?

Comment: What are the bounds on $a$ and $b$? Are they known values, integers, reals, etc.?

Comment: @horchler a and b are real known numbers. b=13.2pi and a=36

Answer (score 1):

As it currently stands, the integral diverges due to the behavior of the [Struve **H** function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) on $\mathbb R^-.~$ However, on $\mathbb R^+$ we have :

> $$\int_0^\infty\exp(-x\text{ sinh }u)~Y_0(x)~dx~=~-\frac2\pi~\frac{u}{\cosh u}$$
>
> ---
>
> $$\int_0^\infty\exp(-x\text{ csch }u)~H_0(x)~dx~=~+\frac2\pi~\frac{u}{\coth u}$$